# Setting up Bluehost with Heroku and Google G-suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, google-workspace

I have my domain name purchased on Bluehost.  I have my website application hosted by Heroku. I have my email setup with Google G-suite.

I setup the 5 MX records in the Bluehost zone editor as per Google's instructions, however, I cannot receive any emails.  Google told me my nameservers are not active, however my domain name successfully directs to my Heroku app - so that's the first thing I don't understand.

Bluehost told me that I need to stop pointing at their nameservers and provide them with nameservers from Heroku but I cannot find this information.

Anyone know how to setup Bluehost to operate successfully with Heroku and Google mail?

Comment: Can you provide the domain name so I can `dig` the records?

Comment: I would prefer not to publish this. Was hoping somebody with Heroku application experience (and using Bluehost) has already solved this and worked out what nameservers to use (if that's the solution of course).

Comment: Can you redact the domain name? It's going to be hard to debug without seeing if the records have been implemented correctly. Have you tried to `dig` the records in a terminal? Is so you should see `300 IN MX 10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.` being returned. And there should be five separate records.

Comment: 2.  In Bluehost I have mapped the domain name to the Heroku app using the CNAME and this seems to work fine when I go to the domain URL

Comment: 3.  In Bluehost, the nameservers are mapped to the default Bluehost nameservers - I do not know if this is what I need to do or not. That's one question.  Heroku told me:  "Your DNS provider will host your nameservers -- not Heroku".   Next question I have is: is Bluehost my "DNS Provider" - is that the right thing to call it?

Comment: 4.  Finally to summarise...  (A) the domain name directs to the Heroku app ok (I guess because of the CNAME setting), (B) I cannot receive emails to Gmail as it reports not finding the nameservers error  (C) I do not know what to use for nameservers, or fix this issue.

Comment: Prefect. So to confirm you have no MX records set up on the domain as no records are being returned when I `dig` the MX records of the domain. Did you follow [the instructions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6149032?hl=en) on G Suite support?

Comment: As I said in my original problem statement: "I setup the 5 MX records in the Bluehost zone editor as per Google's instructions"

Comment: You have not set them up correctly then as they are not viewable in the public DNS and this is why you are getting the Google error. I can see the CNAME pointing to Heroku. Did you try with the [Bluehost](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/mx) instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Explanation to save others time (5 hrs chat / 2 hrs phone support): (1) Heroku does not supply nameservers. Therefore your DNS provider (or other company) needs to. (2) Even though the domain name successfully pointed to my Heroku app via the CNAME record, the Bluehost guy was surprised this worked at all without nameservers setup. (3) Solution: I needed to purchase the basic hosting plan from BH which activated the nameservers. My mails started to be received at Google mail. I had to re-enter the MX records for Google & the CNAME record for my Heroku app in the BH zone editor.